# What is the easiest and most reliable MySQL data provider for .NET Apps?

Tags: c#, mysql, vb.net, odbc

There are a [couple](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/dotnet/index.html) of data providers to interface with MySQL databases from .NET Apps. Which in your experience have you found the easiest to work with and most reliable?

- MySQL .NET Connector
- MyODBC
- dotConnect for MySQL
- other

I've never done this before so I want to walk down a path that's tried and tested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MySQL Connector/NET works very well, it supports advanced stuff like Entity Framework, it's very actively developed and the support is good. It's very reliable mature software. The only thing you should be careful with is that sometimes they like to introduce breaking changes.

And it's open source!

Comment: Easy, perhaps. Reliable? Not from what I have encountered.

Comment: @MaxToro - Do you use this connector? Does it work very well for you? There are severe issues with complex linq that it does not support and numerous unfixed reported issues dating back to 2009. It is easy. But it does not work "very well" for complex scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **System.Data.Odbc** connections and connection string as it:

```
DRIVER={MySql ODBC 3.51 Driver}; SERVER=localhost; DATABASE=***; DATASOURCE=***; UID=***;PASSWORD=***
```